# How do I move Source Code from a local GitLab to AWS GitLab environment using automation?

Tags: bash, automation, devops, gitlab-ci, sdlc

As a part of my job, I have to automate Sorce code movement from development environment to Production environment. The developers push the code to GitLab that is hosted in the organization's local server. So, every day I take the source code from local GitLab and upload it to AWS hosted GitLab using a Jump Server (Windows 10) and merge the code manually. Now I need to automate it. I have no clue how. This is my first job as a DevOps professional. Guide me what technologies I should use and how I can automate the process.

Comment: The tool you are using for CI should have a method for pullng from a repo. Have you considered that?

Comment: Have you considered using something like [push mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/push.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

[Mirror your repo](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/), as simple as that.

Comment: Is there any alternative to push mirroring? Pull Mirroring is not an option. Can we replace mirroring with any shell script?